Kodak's MOV files - bar on the right and bottom - how to force editors and players to use "width" instead of "original width"? (more in description)
I found a lot of family movies in my old Kodak DX6340 digital camera. Unfortunately, none of the editors (Filmora, Davinci, Movavi, MovieMaker) or any player (except Apple QuickTime Player) can display them correctly - the bar always appears on the right and at the bottom:

I spent many hours looking for the reason and it seems to me that it is because:

Kodak used H263 as the codec
H263 codec has a native (one of many) resolution of 352x288 (does not support 320x240)
Kodak in its camera specifications:
link 1
states that the videos are 320x240 and that is how they are played when I connect the camera to a TV with a cable or when I play them on my computer using QuickTime Player:



The MediaInfo application gives the same size:



and now the most important thing: MediaInfo gives the following data:


With/Height = 320/240,
Original Width/Original height = 352/288,
Display aspect Ratio = 4:3
So, when I try to open this MOV in movie editors or players - those applications look at the wrong parameters. They should look at 320/240 and 4:3. And they look at 352x288 (additionally - it is not 4:3!) so then they artificially draw this black bar on the right and at the bottom.
Is there any way to force the appropriate interpretation on the MOV header? For example, by modifying this header somehow?
If anyone would like to see it on their own, I am attaching this MOV file:
MOV file


Have you tried MPC-HC video player? It has options to control display of the video frame, as shown below. Perhaps one of thsoe settings will be correct for the Kodak video.



Particular videos can be loaded in an editor, such asOpenShot Video Editor or Shotcut (both are free and open source) and exported in any format desired: correctly-sized MOV, AVI, MP4, etc. This has the advantage of enabling editing, such as improving contrast, stabilizing, dubbing sound, etc.
Try a batch conversion tool, such as Allard's File Converter, to see if it can convert all files at once, after testing if settings can correct the size mismatch on one file.


Thanks, unfortunately, MPC-HC adds that phantom black bars too... All editors I tried (Filmora, Davinci, Movavi, MovieMaker) have the same problem. The idea of converting is very bad in this example - the movie has only 320x240 - can't crop/resize/stretch/re-decode - it will eat the details (if I could say, that 320x240 has any details...;-) )
